# UserControl created with DataTemplate has dispose issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have 4 different view with different kind of operation. I am using DateTemplate to create View

```
<DateTemplate DateType={X:Type HomeViewModel}" >
     <HomeView>
</DateTemplate>
<DateTemplate DateType={X:Type DeviceDateViewModel}" >
     <DeviceDateView>
</DateTemplate>
```

and I have ContentControl and all ViewModels are bound to Content property, say "ActiveView"

I have created all ViewModel and kept in dictionary. When I want to change the view, I just assign ActiveView to the new one which I want to show.

```
void ActiveteView(ViewType viewType)
{
    ActiveView = GetViewFromDictionary(viewType);
}
```

One of our control doesn't support DataBinding, so I have created some new controls in View's behind code.

My problem is : when I change the ActiveView, it creates new View and display's in the ContentControl. Due to that, I'm getting the problem. My old View's are still in memory. How to destroy them?

At this point of time, we can't change the Design. We are in the situation to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the vm is in the dictionary then garbage collection will not collect it. There are a bunch of rules as to when GC will collect an object, I myself have to refresh myself on the topic occasionally. [All about Garbage collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There are ways to force a garbage collection but IMHO that obviates the benefits of using [managed code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Generally speaking as long as your not holding on to a reference to that object GC should eventually collect it. You can force such collection but that would be an indication that something is wrong with your design.

According to MSDN:

> "It is possible to force garbage collection by calling Collect, but most of the time, this should be avoided because it may create performance issues. "

Comment: i am not disposing VM and i no need to do that when application is alive. My problem is, when i change the ActiveView, WPF DateTemplate (i believe IOC does this behind) creates new View and try to destroy the old one. Here we have reference of 3'r part control. So that view is not destroyed.

Comment: How does it go about trying to destroy the old one? Does it call IDisposable.Dispose or the ~finalizer? Perhaps putting code in either of those to de-reference the part control will work. This doesn't seem like a good reason to use the ~finalizer but as you say you can not change the design.

Comment: Well, i don't have IDispose. I won't get any benefit even if i add IDisposable interface. I don't have any access to View. In fact, i can't access View object. ~finalizer is also not hitting.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. Finalizer will not run since it is not being garbage collected.

Comment: So you basically have a list of objects. The list you have control of, but the object in the list are off limits. Something keeps creating new objects and adding them to the list. Is this correct?

Comment: Okay, you are new to MVVM is my understanding. Any way, ActiveView is type of ViewModel base. First i assign HomeViewModel to ActiveView and then when i assign DeviceDataViewModel, behind it creates new DeviceDataView instead of using the same view which is already in memory.

Comment: I'm familiar with MVVM, perhaps just not they way you are doing it. I've used MVVM light mostly, and rolled my own in a past life. Exactly how much memory is this consuming, is it a problem? **How about making parts of your view static?**